# Why is Alamofire taking so long to timeout when there is no network connection?

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

I'm using `Swift 3.0` with `Alamofire 4`. I am using a singleton network class to make `API` requests to a server. When there is no internet, Alamofire takes about 30 seconds to finish the closure and run the failure handler. Here is my code:

```
func performRequest(_ url:String,completionHandler:@escaping (_ Success:Bool,AnyObject?) -> Void) {

    Alamofire.request(url).validate().responseJSON { response in

        if response.result.isSuccess { //Request was successful
            self.errorCount = 0
            completionHandler(true,response.result.value as AnyObject?)
        } else {
            print("failure occured")
            self.setNoInternetDialogAppear()
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried setting the timeout using this code, but it has no effect:

```
`Alamofire.SessionManager.default.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 2000`
```

I recently migrated my code from Swift 2.2 and Alamofire 3 and has only started happening since. TIA

Comment: You must set the `waitsForConnectivity` flag before creating the session. The session takes a copy of the configuration so changing it afterwards has no effect on the created session.

Answer (score 0):

```
var alamoFireManager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
self.alamoFireManager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 2000
....
self.alamoFireManager.request(...)
```

Using the variable worked.

Comment: Thank you. Just tried this and still experiencing the long timeout.

Comment: It seems the timeout is exactly 60 seconds. I have put "print" methods with the times of the outputs.

Comment: Weird! I'm using this exact method with:

 pod 'AlamofireDomain', '4.1'

Sorry, wish I could help you further.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to test the network connection before firing off the alamofire request. Try this function.

```
class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.size)
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    guard let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress, {
        $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, $0)
        }
    }) else {
        return false
    }

    var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = []
    if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) {
        return false
    }

    let isReachable = flags.contains(.reachable)
    let needsConnection = flags.contains(.connectionRequired)

    return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still trying to understand why Alamofire is taking so long to finish a request with no internet, but if you just want to change the Timeout interval, you can use an [URLSessionConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration) object.

- **Alamofire 5+**
- **Swift 5+**

---

```
init(interceptor: RequestInterceptor) {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = HTTPHeaders.default.dictionary
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 15
    self.session = Session(configuration: configuration, interceptor: interceptor)
}
```